# Group by clause always produces error "Not a group by expression"

Tags: sql, join, group-by, subquery, create-table

I have two tables

```
EMPLOYEES(employee_id,first_name,last_name,salary,manager_id,department_id)
and 
DEPARTMENTS(department_id,department_name,manager_id)
```

When I try to create a new table "EMP_DEPT" which contains

```
department_id ,department_name, dcount(count of employees in each department), 
dtotal(total salary of employees in each department),
dmaxsal(maximum salary in a department), dminsal(minimum salary in a department)
```

it shows **ORA00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

I did this in oracle

```
create table emp_dept as(select e.department_id,d.department_name,count(*),sum(salary),max(salary),min(salary)
from employees e,departments d where e.department_id= d.department_id
group by e.department_id);
```

Comment: Try adding `d.department_name` to your `group by` clause.  Also consider using the standard `join` syntax, although that wouldn't cause the error.

Comment: it works! but why we need d.department_name? e.department_id is enough?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused in writing your query.

First of all, You are using aliases in columns of table `departments`, but you're not using aliases in columns of table `employees`.

```
 select e.department_id,d.department_name,count(*),sum(salary),max(salary),min(salary)
 from employees e,departments d
```

Secondly, you're using a `where` clause, but shouldn't a `left join` be a better choice?

```
  where e.department_id= d.department_id
```

Thirdly, and most importantly, you're doing `group by` in `e.department_id`, whereas it should be `d.department_id` , since there is a parent-child relationship among the tables `departments` and `employees`. I don't know how you designed your table, but logically, `department_id` is supposed to be the primary key in `departments` table, and foreign key in `employees` table. That's why, `group by e.department_id` is incorrect.

Therefore,

```
  group by e.department_id
```

Should instead be,

```
  group by d.department_id
```

I think you just need to modify your query in the following way:

```
create table emp_dept as
(select d.department_id,d.department_name,count(e.*),
sum(e.salary),max(e.salary),min(e.salary)
from departments d 
left join employees e
on e.department_id= d.department_id
group by d.department_id);
```

And hopefully it will fix your problem.